# Relation between ng-model variable and local controller variable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have one issue with my simple angularjs project.

JS File

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('AppController', AppController);
  function AppController() {
    var vm = this;
    var photos = ["sample.png","sample.png"];
    init();

    function init() {
      vm.photolist = photos;
    }
  }
}());
```

View File

```
<div ng-repeat="photo in vm.photolist track by $index">
  <input type = "text" ng-model="vm.photolist[$index]">
</div>
<button class="resetbutton" type="button" ng-click="vm.init()">
```

when i click button(class=resetbutton) I want to set vm.photolist as initial state ["sample.png","sample.png"].

But If I type something in input box,it is reflected not only vm.photolist but also photos variable.
For example I change first input box as "modified_sample.png", then vm.photolist and photos have same value as ["modified_sample.png","sample.png"].
why is that? I think photos variable shouldn't be changed, and only vm.photolist have to be changed.
What's wrong with my think?

Comment: nothing is wrong. photos variable and vm.photolist refer to the same object. One changes, the other changes too

Comment: Thanks and when i want to not change photos , how to do it?

Comment: Just copy your array instead of assign reference.
    vm.photolist = angular.copy(photos);